# How to get latitude and longitude from address google map using php

Tags: php, google-maps

I have an Address and using that I want to fetch its exact Latitude and Longitude,

but when I run my code it is giving me some other locations latitude and Longitude.

**Output I want**

[image]

**Output I am getting**

[image]

Please help me

Thanks in advance

```
<?php
$address = 'Cafe Coffee Day, INSIDE HPCL Petrol Bunk, Mumbai - Goa Highway,    
Mangaon, Maharashtra, India'; 
$prepAddr = str_replace(' ','+',$address);

$geocode=file_get_contents('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?     
address='.$prepAddr.'&sensor=false');

$output= json_decode($geocode);

// echo "<pre>";
// print_r($output);

$lat = $output->results[0]->geometry->bounds->northeast->lat;
$long = $output->results[0]->geometry->bounds->northeast->lng;
// $lati=round($lat,6);
// $longi=round($long,6);

echo $address.'<br>Lat: '.$lat.'<br>Long: '.$long;

?>
```

Comment: Try the `location`, not `northeast`. Also your requesting URL has a space between the address parameter this causes it to fail currently, could that be the issue? Can you describe `inaccurate` more?

Comment: @chris85 Actually i am getting lat and long but it is giving me some other location than the address

Comment: Okay, so use the `location`, or use the `northeast` and the `southwest` bounding points. Or update the question with what you currently get and what was/is expected.

Comment: @DharmeshPatel you will not get exact location by address. you will get lat long of nearby location.

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this:

```
<?php
$address = "Cafe Coffee Day, INSIDE HPCL Petrol Bunk, Mumbai - Goa Highway,    Mangaon, Maharashtra, India";
 $url = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=".urlencode($address)."&sensor=false&region=India";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, 3128);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$response_a = json_decode($response);
echo $lat = $response_a->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
echo "<br />";
echo $long = $response_a->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;

?>
```

Output is [image]

Comment: getting same output.

Comment: remove(,) from address and use proper address and do not use space.use(+)

Comment: @DharmeshPatel it work for me could you please tell me which type of adress you are passing ($address = "India+jaipur+vaishalinagar";)

Comment: @DharmeshPatel please use  this  `$address = "Cafe Coffee Day, INSIDE HPCL Petrol Bunk, Mumbai - Goa Highway,    
Mangaon, Maharashtra, India";
$url = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=".urlencode($address)."&sensor=false&region=India";`

Answer (score 0):

```
$lat = $output->results[0]->geometry->bounds->northeast->lat;
$long = $output->results[0]->geometry->bounds->northeast->lng;
```

change to:

```
$lat = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
$long = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;
```

Comment: did you also change variable names in echo? I mean $lati -> $lat and $longi->$long in echo statement.

Answer (score 0):

Change you echo statement to

```
echo $address.'<br>Lat: '.$lat.'<br>Long: '.$long;
```

Note: Remove the trailing i from your variables

Comment: Sorry it was a typo.